# Can I use future tense here?

Tags: grammar, future

I know future tense cannot be used in time clauses. I would like to know, is the following incorrect?

> You have to launch the game and quit the game before the file will show up.

I think it is as I cannot use "before" and future tense. However, it does not sound like purely time clause (I cannot "ask" properly WHEN.)

Comment: "I know future tense cannot be used in time clauses." I have no idea what that means.

Comment: @Blessed Geek: I think it's what they say in some ESL classes so that students don't make the mistake of saying "I will meet you at the airport when you *will come tomorrow" ... the second "will" here is indeed ungrammatical.

Comment: Yes, but they get the rule wrong, of course. An ESL Zombie Rule, wow. It's not "future tense"; it's the **epistemic sense** of the modal auxiliary _will_. And it's not in "time clauses", it's in **hypothetical** clauses. And it's not that you can't use _will_ in hypotheticals, it's just that you don't get the epistemic reading, only the deontic one that means 'be willing to'. Whence the Volition I mention.

Answer (score 7):

Perfectly grammatical and meaningful in both cases.

The use of *will* in a potentially counterfactual *before* clause allows a [deontic interpretation of *will*](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html), however, which highlights the necessity of **both** launching, **and** then quitting, the game **first**, in order to get the file to show up afterwards.

This is because *before NP will VP* clauses indicate that NP is not normally *willing* to VP without the preparations in the main clause.

- You have to tell him three times before he'll believe you.
- You have to hold down the ALT key while pressing CTRL-P before it'll print.

Volition is not normally attributable to inanimate things, but software is easy to personify, especially in pejorative, refractory ways.

Answer (score 2):

Let us presume you are a technical writer for computer software operation.

You are specifying the required sequence of stimulus that would promote an outcome.

First, let us establish the required stimulus leading to the outcome.

```
if (game is launched) then // First stimulus
{
  if (game has quit) then // 2nd stimulus requring 1st stimulus
  {
    display file.
  }
}
```

Therefore, your statement should be

> You have to launch the game and **then** quit the game, before the file
>   $will be displayed.

Where $will is either

will, can, would, could, should or might.

Secondly, we have to establish the mood of your specification.

- the file will certainly show up, no doubt about it.
- the file can show up, but there are more conditions to be satisfied.
- the file could possibly show up, due to ill-defined circumstances.
- the file should show up, I believe so hmm... because it is the expected outcome.
- the file might show up, but we hope it would not.

3rdly, let us clarify the word "will". There are two distinct usages here.

- will = having the propensity to show up. As in "the will to survive".
- an implied assertion of future tense due to unsatisfied conditions/stimulus that have yet to occur.

Let us lean towards

> will = having the propensity (spontaneous tendency) to be displayed.

and that the mood of your specification is

> the file will certainly show up, no doubt about it.

Therefore, your specification should be:

> You have to launch the game and **then** quit the game, before the file
>   will be displayed.

or

> You have to launch the game and **then** quit the game, before the file
>   will show up.

Answer (score 0):

Because "the file will show up" is a dependent clause used after conditional conjunction "before", I think that Simple Present should be used

Answer (score -2):

> You have to launch the game and quit the game before the file shows up.